# Convert Robot IDE to generic Robot tests

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am working with existing Robot IDE tests, which we would like to use with Jenkins and other tools to add continuous integration into the work flow. So far, I haven't found a way to use Robot IDE with Jenkins and other tools. Is it possible to convert tests built in the IDE to a more standard format that we can run in the console?

Answer (score 2):

You won't use RIDE with Jenkins. RIDE is just to create/run/update your tests with a GUI. What you have to do is to get familiar with the tests files on the file system, and launch Robot Framework via command line (with pybot). Once this works, create a Job in Jenkins with the same command line.

You could check a [blog post](http://laurent.bristiel.com/create-jenkins-job-for-robot-framework/) I wrote couple of days ago on the same topic.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert anything. Just feed them to pybot/jybot/ipybot. RIDE is just an editor, it's nothing more. You don't need RIDE at all. How to run tests is thoroughly documented in the user guide.

See [Executing test cases](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-test-cases)